# How to ask "Can you still speak Chinese?" in Chinese Mandarin?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

I think I can say like this `你还能说中文吗` to ask whether someone still can speak Chinese or not. But I doubt about the word `can`.

It seems like the following words can all mean `can`:

- 可
- 能
- 会

Which word is the most common use for the word `can`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"你还**能**说中文吗?" = "**Can** you still speak English?" (**have the ability/ able to** to speak Chinese)

"你还**可**说中文吗?" =  "**Can** you still speak Chinese?" (**allowed** to speak Chinese)

"你还**会**说中文吗?" =  1. "**Can** you still speak Chinese?" (**know how to** speak Chinese) 2. "**Would** you still speak Chinese?" (**willing to/ would** speak Chinese)

Although 会 can mean 'know how to' or 'would', "你还会说中文吗?" is still the most native way to say "Can you still speak Chinese", and "你还**能**说中文吗?" is also grammatical

Comment: 可 is never used like this in modern colloquial Mandarin, though. It would be 可**以**说 instead, unless in archaic style or a set phrase like 无话可说.

Comment: 可 is more May than Can.

Comment: What should 你还可能说中文吗 mean? Sometimes, I saw people use both 可能 in one sentence.

Comment: 你还可能说中文吗 (can you still possibly speak Chinese)? is an odd question to ask. 那个人可能会中文 (that person may know Chinese) would be a valid sentence

Answer (score 1):

你还会说中文吗?
is the best way to ask: Can you still speak Chinese?